# How can I detect if a gameObject has collided with two other specific objects at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I detect if a gameObject has collided with two other specific objects **at the same time?**

This is what I intend to do but it does not work:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{

if(col.gameObject.name == "object1" && "object2")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

How can I correct this piece of code?

Comment: Try it here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When are you calling this ? `OnCollisionEnter` ?

Comment: Yes.     OnCollisionEnter

Answer (score 1):

If you are colliding with 2 objects the method OnCollisionEnter will be called twice, so you must keep track of their gameobject or names.

```
List<string> contacts = new List<string>();
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    contacts.Add(col.gameObject.name);
    if(contacts.Contains("object1") && contacts.Contains("object2"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
{
    contacts.Remove(col.gameObject.name);
}
```

but remember to add the reference to get the lists to work

```
using System.Collections.Generics;
```

Comment: Can you please explain step by step your code? And where is object2?

Comment: I am fairly new to programming and Unity.

Comment: we have a list that can contain strings
When an object collides with the object that has this script attached, the other object's name will be added to the list.
And then the code check if there are the 2 objects names.
So if it is true the object will be destroyed.

Comment: Is this code meant for two objects colliding with another one at the same time or for the moment when there are at least two named objects attached to another object (then execute an action...)?

Comment: if your object have both collided with the two objects and they are still colliding then execute action.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are checking collisions on any of the events fired regarding collison,
like `Collider.OnCollisionEnter` `Collider.OnCollisionStay` `Collider.OnCollisionExit`, you could get **ALL** the `Contact` points from the `Collision` parameter passed by the event by

`Collision.contacts` and you could get the `gameObject` by Enumerating the `ContactPoint`s in `Collision.contacts` and this :
`ContactPoint.otherCollider.gameObject` and check its name :)

Hope it helped :)

More info : [Collision Contacts - Unity Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html)

Comment: All of the `ContactPoint`s for a single `Collision` refer to the same `gameObject`, so this is not enough to solve the problem